# How to include constrast+saturation filter after vidstabtransform?

Tags: ffmpeg, contrast

In a previous question, I got help in fixing the code as stated below. However, I realize that my output file is slightly lower in contrast and saturation.

Is there any way to append a contrast+saturation filter to the output stabilized file?

```
'" @For %%A In (*.mov)Do @(
    ffmpeg -i "%%A" -vf vidstabdetect=shakiness=8:accuracy=15:stepsize=6:mincontrast=0.4:show=2 -y -an -f null -
    ffmpeg -i "%%A" -vf vidstabtransform=smoothing=15:input="transforms.trf":interpol=linear:crop=black:zoom=0:optzoom=1,unsharp=5:5:0.8:3:3:0.4 -vcodec libx264 -tune film -y "%%~nAstabilized.mp4"
)

pause '"
```

Answer (score 0):

You chain additional filters:

```
'" @For %%A In (*.mov)Do @( ffmpeg -i "%%A" -vf vidstabdetect=shakiness=8:accuracy=15:stepsize=6:mincontrast=0.4:show=2 -y -an -f null - ffmpeg -i "%%A" -vf vidstabtransform=smoothing=15:input="transforms.trf":interpol=linear:crop=black:zoom=0:optzoom=1,unsharp=5:5:0.8:3:3:0.4,hue=s=1.2,curves=preset=medium_contrast -vcodec libx264 -tune film -y "%%~nAstabilized.mp4" )

pause '"
```

This example adds the [hue](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#hue) and [curves](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#curves) filters. Refer to the [filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html) for more info or if you prefer some other filter combination.

Comment: oh thank you! i didn't realize it's just a comma. i went to do another -vf eq=constrast... hence it ended up not knowing which filter to apply.. Thanks!!